# Detect when register to the property change event

Tags: c#, events, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

I have a `Property Change` event and I want to know when register to it.

Here my event in `class1`:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Here my register in `class2` (`MyObj` is an instance of a `Class1`):

```
 MyObj.PropertyChanged += MyObj_PropertyChanged;
```

When the registration is happening, I want to run a specific function (from `class1`), how can I do it?

I could not find any way to do so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax to declare event:

```
class MyClass
{
    private EventHandler myEvent;

    private void OnEventHandlerRegistered()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event handler registered.");
    }

    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add 
        {
            myEvent += value;
            OnEventHandlerRegistered();
        }
        remove
        {
            myEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I do that, I get an error message on this line: `if (PropertyChanged != null)`

Comment: @HodayaShalom: of course you will get it. You should test for `null` backing field (`myEvent` in sample) in this case.